# Sapper server-side rendering (SSR) doesn’t work on Zeit Now v2

Tags: svelte, vercel, sapper

I’ve taken the source code from https://github.com/beyonk-adventures/now-sapper-demo and just used `now` to deploy it on Zeit Now v2.

See https://test-v2-qa.tomsoderlund.now.sh/blog

You see that `/blog` returns 500 error:

```
request to http://127.0.0.1:0/blog.json failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1
```

But https://test-v2-qa.tomsoderlund.now.sh/blog.json returns valid JSON, so something with how the URL is requested?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @thgh, who helped me: https://github.com/beyonk-adventures/now-sapper-demo/issues/5#issuecomment-583779955

For anyone else with the same problem; I made this helper function:

```
export default function zeitNowUrl (path, host = '') {
  const baseUrl = (!process.browser && process.env.NOW_REGION)
    ? `https://${host}`
    : ''
  return `${baseUrl}/${path}`
}
```

...and then in each page:

```
<script context="module">
  import zeitNowUrl from '../../lib/zeitNowUrl'

  export function preload({ host, params, query }) {
    return this.fetch(zeitNowUrl('blog.json', host)).then(r => r.json()).then(posts => {
      return { posts }
    })
  }
</script>
```

#### Update

This is now fixed in `now-sapper` v0.39.0.